# Latex command for unfilled \bigstar

Tags: xetex, symbols, luatex, unicode-math

`\bigstar` produces a black star.
What is the LaTeX command for white or unfilled `\bigstar`?

The `unicode-math` package has a command `\bigwhitestar`, but I am not able to use it in the usual way. When I compile with `\usepackage{unicode-math}`, I get the following error:

```
! Package unicode-math Error: Cannot be run with pdfLaTex!
(unicode-math)         Use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTex instead.
```

PS: I need the big white star symbol to reference a point in a Matlab generated figure.
I cannot compile with xetex or xelatex because they do not use the conference style file properly, i.e. the output looks quite different from that of latex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `comprehensive` list suggests the following options:

1. `\usepackage{bbding}`, then `\FiveStarOpen`
2. `\usepackage{pifont}`, `\ding{80}`
3. `\usepackage{MnSymbol}`, `$\largestar$`

And here is the comparison:

[image]

Comment: The usual *caveat* about `MnSymbol`: it changes *all* math symbols.

Comment: Note that one should use `\mbox{\FiveStarOpen}` or `\mbox{\ding{80}}` (there's also `\ding{73}`, by the way). If `amsmath` is loaded, use `\text` instead of `\mbox`, so the symbol will properly scale in subscripts and superscripts.

Answer (score 8):

If your require some tuning of the star border, this solution is an alternative.  The downside is that it loads a lot of packages; however, none of those packages overwrite the existing fonts, in the way that `MnSymbol` does.

In this case `\openbigstar` takes an optional argument specifying the relative size of the inner white star relative to the outer black star, thus defining a border thickness in the process.  And using `scalerel` package's features, it automatically works across different math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\openbigstar[1][0.7]{%
  \scalerel*{%
    \stackinset{c}{-.125pt}{c}{}{\scalebox{#1}{\color{white}{$\bigstar$}}}{%
      $\bigstar$}%
  }{\bigstar}
}
\begin{document}
$\bigstar\openbigstar\openbigstar[.4]\openbigstar[.9]$
$\scriptstyle\bigstar\openbigstar\openbigstar[.4]\openbigstar[.9]$
$\scriptscriptstyle\bigstar\openbigstar\openbigstar[.4]\openbigstar[.9]$
\end{document}
```

[image]