# Latex command for plus-over-cross

Tags: symbols, math-operators

I want to use the symbol 'plus-over-cross' to refer to point in a Matlab generated figure. 
In LaTex terms this will be an overlay of + over \times. Any ideas?

Note that I do not want the asterisk symbol.

Comment: Generally http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html helps you to answer such questions. But it doesnt seem to be the case that such a character exists in any package. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21644/how-do-you-superimpose-two-symbols-over-each-other might be a relevant answer for you.

Comment: Yes, I tried detexify. And also documentations of unicode-math, bbding, pifont, etc. But didn't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar to another recent answer ([Latex command for unfilled \bigstar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156712/latex-command-for-unfilled-bigstar/156731#156731)), and uses a `\stackinset` to achieve the goal.  The `\scalerel` is used to make it work across math style sizes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\pluscross{\scalerel*{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{$+$}{$\times$}}{+}}
\begin{document}
$+\times\pluscross$
$\scriptstyle+\times\pluscross$
$\scriptscriptstyle+\times\pluscross$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You also can use the \mathrlap from the mathtools package: $\mathrlap{\times}+$.

Comment: @Bernard It seems that approach was similar to shess' answer, except without the math sizes.  Thanks for the tip.  I would add that the `\rlap` approach works only because both character components are the same width and height.  `\stackinset` would allow for a correction if that were not the case.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I didn't see this answer that was given while I checked whether it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Another way, based on the rlap as mentioned in the post linked in my first commment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\newcommand{\foo}{\rlap{+}{\texttimes}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
this symbol consists of two: \foo
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`\mathpalette` and `\ooalign` are easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\plustimes}{\mathpalette\plustimesinner\relax}
\newcommand{\plustimesinner}[2]{%
  \mathbin{\vphantom{+}\ooalign{$#1+$\cr\hidewidth$#1\times$\hidewidth\cr}}%
}

\begin{document}
$+\times\plustimes$
$\scriptstyle+\times\plustimes$
$\scriptscriptstyle+\times\plustimes$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one doesn't want to risk cases where `\mathsurround` is non zero, the definition of `\plustimesinner` should be changed into

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\plustimesinner}[2]{%
  \mathbin{\vphantom{+}\ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1+$\cr
    \hidewidth$\m@th#1\times$\hidewidth\cr}}%
}
\makeatother
```