# Latex command for unfilled star

Tags: symbols

I would like to use `\medstar` from the `MnSymbol` package, but it seems that `MnSymbol` conflicts with other packages I am using including `amsmath`.

I've tried to use `\FiveStarOpen` from `bbding` as suggested here: [Latex command for unfilled \bigstar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156712/latex-command-for-unfilled-bigstar)

But for some reason `\FiveStarOpen` does not display an unfilled star, but the figure '9' instead.

Here is the list of packages that I am using: `cite`, `graphicx`, `epstopdf`, `tikz,` `amsmath`, `amsfonts`, `amsthm`, `cancel`, `array`, `mdwmath`, `mdwtab`, `fixltx2e`, `url`, `color`, `enumerate`, and `comment`.

I am a beginner at LaTEX, so any help will be greatly appreciated!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{cancel} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{mdwmath} 
\usepackage{mdwtab} 
\usepackage{fixltx2e} 
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{bbding}

\begin{document}
\FiveStarOpen
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a full  [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work. Rather than just listing the packages that you use it really helps if you can provide a *minimal* template for your tex file so that people can test it to see how to help you.

Comment: What about `\usepackage{pifont}` and `\ding{73}`? However, in math you should use `\text{\ding{73}}` and, similarly,  `\text{\FiveStarOpen}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The suggestions in [Latex command for unfilled \bigstar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156712/latex-command-for-unfilled-bigstar) are good, but they miss a point: if you need the hollow star in math mode, you need to box it.

Since you're using `amsmath`, you can do with

```
\newcommand{\hollowstar}{\text{\FiveStarOpen}}
```

It's convenient to define a special command, because in this way you can at any moment change the definition in just one place and so modify all appearances of the symbol in the document.

For instance, if you decide to go for `\ding{73}` of the `pifont` package (which might be convenient because it is a Type1 font, while `bbding` is only available in bitmap form), you can simply change the above line into

```
\newcommand{\hollowstar}{\text{\ding{73}}}
```

and all appearances of `\hollowstar` will change after a run of LaTeX.

Note that if you want to assign the symbol the meaning of a binary operation, you should define

```
\newcommand{\hollowstar}{\mathbin{\text{\FiveStarOpen}}}
```

If a binary relation, use `\mathrel`.